# Renaming multiple files & re-number files

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have many files in a folder like:

```
ConstantText1_variable_name_1_-_Constant_Text2_1233.png
ConstantText1_variable_name_1_-_Constant_Text2_1234.png
ConstantText1_variable_name_1_-_Constant_Text2_1235.png

ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1236.png
ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1237.png
ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1238.png
ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1239.png

ConstantText1_another_variable_name_3_-_Constant_Text2_1240.png
ConstantText1_another_variable_name_3_-_Constant_Text2_1241.png
```

I would like to rename them so they become:

```
variable_name_1_01.png
variable_name_1_02.png
variable_name_1_03.png

variable_name_2_01.png
variable_name_2_02.png
variable_name_2_03.png
variable_name_2_04.png

another_variable_name_3_01.png
another_variable_name_3_02.png
```

I've tried various scripts to get the file names and manipulate the strings but couldn't get any of them to work.
I've been using BulkRenameUtility and renaming each "variable_name" separately but I would rather use a more efficient and easy method. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they do contain different numbers of underscores. That's one of the problems I was experiencing as well, trying to use tokens in a batch file.

Comment: Yes, .vbs would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch processing:

```sh
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set number=1
set prevstr=*
for /f %%x in ('dir /b *.png') do (
    call :sub %%x
)
endlocal
goto :eof

:sub
set tmpstr=%1
set tmpstr=%tmpstr:ConstantText1_=%
set tmpstr=%tmpstr:_-_Constant_Text2_=*%
for /f "tokens=1 delims=*" %%x in ("%tmpstr%") do (
    if not %prevstr%==%%x ( 
        set number=1
        set prevstr=%%x
    )
    echo ren "%1" "%%x_!number!.png"
    set /a number+=1
)
exit /b
```

> Is there a way to get the numbers padded? ex)[01, 02, ..., 09, 10] instead of [1, 2, ..., 9, 10]?

Of course. Look - I use zero-padding till 3 digits, alter the amount if needed

```sh
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set number=1
set prevstr=*
for /f %%x in ('dir /b *.png') do (
    call :sub %%x
)
endlocal
goto :eof

:sub
set tmpstr=%1
set tmpstr=%tmpstr:ConstantText1_=%
set tmpstr=%tmpstr:_-_Constant_Text2_=*%
for /f "tokens=1 delims=*" %%x in ("%tmpstr%") do (
    if not %prevstr%==%%x ( 
        set number=1
        set prevstr=%%x
    )
:: zero padding to 3 digits, for another length alter next 2 lines accordingly
    set padded=000!number!
    echo ren "%1" "%%x_!padded:~-3!.png"
    set /a number+=1
)
exit /b
```

Comment: This is about what I got working but the problem is I need the numbering to reset for each "variable_name" and there are variable number of "_"/underscore characters in the file names.
  
In solution above "another_variable_name_3_1.png" should be the first result. orz

Comment: @EthanHlc Updated. Test...

Comment: I had parenthesis in some of the file names, but I used a few workarounds and got it working in the end. Is there a way to get the numbers padded? ex)[01, 02, ..., 09, 10] instead of [1, 2, ..., 9, 10]??

Comment: @EthanHlc Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that relies on two hybrid batch/JScript utility scripts:

- [JREN.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) : A regular expression renaming utility
- [JSORT.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) : A sort utility with the ability to output only unique values

Both utilities are pure script that run natively on any Windows machine from XP onward without the need of any 3rd party exe files.

Use `jren /?` and `jsort /?` to get help with the many options available to each utility.

The following code worked for me. Change the definitions of txt1, txt2, and pad as needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "txt1=ConstantText1_"
set "txt2=_-_Constant_Text2_"
set "pad=2"

call :escape txt1
call :escape txt2
set "find=^.*$"

for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in (
  'jren "^%txt1regex%(.*)%txt2regex%.*\.png$" "$1" /i /list /fm "%txt1%*%txt2%*.png" ^| jsort /i /u'
) do (
  set "nm=%%A"
  set "fm=%txt1%%%A%txt2%*.png"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  call jren "!find!" "'!nm!_'+$n+'.png'" /j /npad %pad% /fm !fm!
  endlocal
)
exit /b

:escape
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "txt=!%~1!"
set "txt=!txt:.=\.!"
set "txt=!txt:{=\{!"
set "txt=!txt:[=\[!"
set "txt=!txt:^^=\^^!"
set "txt=!txt:$=\$!"
set "txt=!txt:+=\+!"
set "txt=!txt:(=\(!"
set "txt=!txt:)=\)!"
endlocal & set "%~1regex=%txt%"
exit /b
```

Here is sample output showing that the above script worked with the sample file names. I called the script "test.bat"

```
C:\test\renameTest>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5ED1-638E

 Directory of C:\test\renameTest

02/27/2020  11:23 PM    <DIR>          .
02/27/2020  11:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 ConstantText1_another_variable_name_3_-_Constant_Text2_1240.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 ConstantText1_another_variable_name_3_-_Constant_Text2_1241.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 ConstantText1_variable_name_1_-_Constant_Text2_1233.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 ConstantText1_variable_name_1_-_Constant_Text2_1234.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 ConstantText1_variable_name_1_-_Constant_Text2_1235.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1236.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1237.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1238.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1239.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM               599 createFiles.bat
02/27/2020  11:23 PM               775 test.bat
              11 File(s)          1,374 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  537,716,002,816 bytes free

C:\test\renameTest>test
"C:\test\renameTest\ConstantText1_another_variable_name_3_-_Constant_Text2_1240.png"  -->  "another_variable_name_3_01.png"
"C:\test\renameTest\ConstantText1_another_variable_name_3_-_Constant_Text2_1241.png"  -->  "another_variable_name_3_02.png"
"C:\test\renameTest\ConstantText1_variable_name_1_-_Constant_Text2_1233.png"  -->  "variable_name_1_01.png"
"C:\test\renameTest\ConstantText1_variable_name_1_-_Constant_Text2_1234.png"  -->  "variable_name_1_02.png"
"C:\test\renameTest\ConstantText1_variable_name_1_-_Constant_Text2_1235.png"  -->  "variable_name_1_03.png"
"C:\test\renameTest\ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1236.png"  -->  "variable_name_2_01.png"
"C:\test\renameTest\ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1237.png"  -->  "variable_name_2_02.png"
"C:\test\renameTest\ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1238.png"  -->  "variable_name_2_03.png"
"C:\test\renameTest\ConstantText1_variable_name_2_-_Constant_Text2_1239.png"  -->  "variable_name_2_04.png"

C:\test\renameTest>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5ED1-638E

 Directory of C:\test\renameTest

02/27/2020  11:23 PM    <DIR>          .
02/27/2020  11:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 another_variable_name_3_01.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 another_variable_name_3_02.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM               599 createFiles.bat
02/27/2020  11:23 PM               775 test.bat
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 variable_name_1_01.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 variable_name_1_02.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 variable_name_1_03.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 variable_name_2_01.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 variable_name_2_02.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 variable_name_2_03.png
02/27/2020  11:21 PM                 0 variable_name_2_04.png
              11 File(s)          1,374 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  537,715,937,280 bytes free

C:\test\renameTest>
```

Comment: I get a "Error: Invalid file name character in Replace" then it says Unable to rename ... for the files.  I tried the code with my files (they have Korean characters) but didn't work, so I tried them with the example filenames above but still got the same error...

Comment: @EthanHlc - It definitely works with the example filenames - see the updated answer. But I suspect it will not work with Korean. I'm assuming Korean uses a variable width character set, and that will not work with JREN or JSORT. Sorry. I'm not sure, but your machine's character set may even prevent the examples from working. But with a "normal" single byte character set it works fine. My [JREPL.BAT utility](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) can work with any character set, but that was a lot of work, and I don't plan on implementing that feature in JREN or JSORT.

Comment: I see. I guess it may be due to the character set then. Thank you anyway, your answer was still useful in learning more about batch processing. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you're ready to explore **PowerShell**:

```
$Folder = $pwd.path   ### Edit appropriately. This is current location.
$CT1 = 'ConstantText1_'
$CT2 = '_Constant_Text2_'
Get-ChildItem $Folder *.png -File | ForEach{
    $_.BaseName -replace $CT1 -replace $CT2 -match '^(\w+)\-(\d+)$' | out-null
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Path'     = $_.FullName
        'BaseName' = $matches[1]
        'Index'    = $matches[2]
    }
} | Group BaseName | ForEach {
    [ref]$i = 1
    $_.Group | Sort Index | 
        Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1:00}.png' -f $_.BaseName, $i.Value++ }
}
```